# Cannot add Sublime project preferences after opening repo via Github Desktop

Tags: sublimetext3, github-for-windows

I have been happy to notice that Github Desktop lets me open a repo in Sublime Text. It seems to open the repo as a project but I have a hard time figuring out how to edit the project preferences for the repo. Specifically, I would like to add `file_exclude_patterns`.

I have tried `Project > Save Project As...` in Sublime, but then when I open the repo through Github Desktop it opens two Sublime windows: one that respects my project preferences and one that ignores them.

Comment: Did you say `Project > Save Project As...` to create the project from the open window?

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes, that's exactly what I did. But then when I try to open the repo in Sublime through Github Desktop it opens two Sublime windows: one that respects my project preferences and one that ignores them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your problem description, it sounds like you might be running into issues with the `hot_exit` setting. When that setting is turned on (which is the default), then whenever you quit Sublime, it saves the state of all open windows into a session file before it quits.

That session file contains a list of every window that's open, what files are open in each, their scroll position, selection, any unsaved changes to files, and so on.  When you restart Sublime, it loads the session file and restores its state back to what it was previously, seamlessly putting you back to where you were before.

One of the potentially unintended side effects of this is that the session is always restored every time you start Sublime. So if you have a project open in a window, and you quit, Sublime keeps a record that you had one window containing that project. If you start it and tell it to open the same project, it will first restore the session and then open the project, resulting in two windows.

As such, turning off `hot_exit` may solve this problem for you. When it's off, the session information isn't saved, and Sublime starts in a more or less "fresh" state every time. The downside to this is that you will be prompted to save all unsaved files, your list of open files is lost, etc. Depending on your use case, this may or may not be an issue.

If you already have that setting off and this still happens, then the issue would be that GitHub for Windows is opening both the project and the folder, which would result in two windows. In that case there's not a lot to do but poke the people in charge of GitHub for Windows and tell them to fix their code.

On the other hand, if you turn off `hot_exit` and you get one window, but it doesn't respect your project preferences, then the problem is that GitHub for Windows is only opening the folder, not the `sublime-project` file.

In that case, there's not a whole lot to be done, unfortunately. Sublime won't load a `sublime-project` file just because it happens to be contained in a folder, since there can conceivably be many of them in there (many people keep their project files in a single folder, for example).

If Sublime is associated with `sublime-project` files, then opening the `sublime-project` file would result in Sublime opening the project for you, so that may be a possibility as well.

Beyond that, you're more or less in the realm of things like using `Project > Switch Project` or `Project > Quick Switch Project` to get the window to display what you want; that's not very handy with regards to just opening the project, though.

Comment: Turning `hot_exit` off fixed the two Sublime windows. Now there is only one window left: the one that ignores the project preferences :(

Comment: I amended my answer above, but basically I think this means that `GfW` is just opening the folder and not the `sublime-project` file; Sublime doesn't automatically load project files that are contained in folders you open.